# correct usage of PositionIncrement

Tags: java, lucene

I recently created a custom TokenFilter to split existing tokens that are `CamelCased` in separate additional tokens. For example, the phrase `MyClassName` would result in the following 4 tokens:
`MyClassName`, `My`, `Class`, `Name`

Here is the code:

```
private class CamelCaseFilter extends TokenFilter {

    private final CharTermAttribute termAttribute = addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
    private final OffsetAttribute offsetAttribute = addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class);
    private final PositionIncrementAttribute posIncAttribute = addAttribute(PositionIncrementAttribute.class);
    
    private boolean processing;
    private int processingIndex;
    private int processingCharPos;
    private String[] splittedValues;
    
    protected CamelCaseFilter(TokenStream input) {
        super(input);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException {
        if (!processing) {
            if (!input.incrementToken()) {
                return false;
            }

            posIncAttribute.setPositionIncrement(1);
            splittedValues = splitCamelCase(termAttribute.toString());
            if (splittedValues.length > 1) {
                processing = true;
                processingIndex = 0;
                processingCharPos = 0;
            }
            return true;
        } 
        
        String part = splittedValues[processingIndex];
        
        termAttribute.setEmpty();
        termAttribute.append(part);
        offsetAttribute.setOffset(processingCharPos, processingCharPos + part.length());
        
        processingCharPos += part.length();
        processingIndex++;
        
        if (processingIndex >= splittedValues.length) {
            processing = false;
        }
        
        return true;
    }

    private static String[] splitCamelCase(String s) {
        // TODO maybe replace with splitByCharacterTypeCamelCase from commons? 
        // http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#splitByCharacterTypeCamelCase%28java.lang.String%29
        return s.split("(?<!(^|[A-Z]))(?=[A-Z])|(?<!^)(?=[A-Z][a-z0-9])");
    }
}
```

My question is, if it is correct (and necessary) to use the `PositionIncrementAttribute` like this. The [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/tokenattributes/PositionIncrementAttribute.html) says:

> Determines the position of this token relative to the previous Token in a TokenStream, used in phrase searching.
>
> The default value is one.
>
> Some common uses for this are:
>
> - Set it to zero to put multiple terms in the same position. This is useful if, e.g., a word has multiple stems. Searches for phrases including either stem will match. In this case, all but the first stem's increment should be set to zero: the increment of the first instance should be one. Repeating a token with an increment of zero can also be used to boost the scores of matches on that token.
> - ...

However, that doesn't really match my usecase. [Another part](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/package-summary.html) also says:

> Note that a filter that filters out tokens must increment the position increment in order not to generate corrupt tokenstream graphs.

In my case I do not remove, but add tokens. Since I keep the original term, but additionally store the parts of it as well, I thought setting the positional increment to zero would be important to not negatively affect search through adding new tokens. Is that the really the case, or did I make a mistake?

Comment: Good question, and in no way is this intended to be an answer to it, but a possible easier solution would be to use [WordDelimiterFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_2_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/WordDelimiterFilter.html).

Comment: @femtoRgon yeah, the only thing is that it doesn't really handle numbers like I want and I'd still have to add the whole word as term - a good hint, nonetheless